# Cannot find Android 11 in SDK Manager

Tags: android, android-studio

I have the last AS version 4.0.1 and wanted to test our apps on Android 11 in the emulator. The docs say that I should see Android 11 in SDK Manager, but it is not there, cf. screenshot

What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: 10.0+ is 11  [from docs](https://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk#update-build) *change .. to ...  `targetSdkVersion 30`* and as you see on your image 10.0+ is api level 30

Comment: aha! This is confusing. The website says:
In Android Studio, click Tools > SDK Manager.
In the SDK Platforms tab, select Show Package Details at the bottom of the window.
Below Android 11 Beta, select a system image such as Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image.

Answer (score 1):

```
Update Android studio to version 4.1.1 latest
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Update the android studio version > 4.1.1
and during prepare system image or say emulator just select api - 30

your new emulator will ready with os -11